# Show info of user by uid from other table

Tags: php, mysql

This is my Rank table

[image]

and this is my users table

[image]
I want to fetch users detail from two tables by using only his UserID.
Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: SO isn't a code broker doing everything for you. Look for `INNER JOIN` and come um with some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

following code will fetch users details from user table

```
select u.* from users u inner join ranks r ON (u.UserID = r.UserID)
```

If you want to get records for specific user lets say userid = 1 then code will be

```
 select u.* from users u inner join ranks r ON (u.UserID = r.UserID) where u.UserID = 1
```

Comment: this is my code http://pastebin.com/F4M9Gj3A
is there any mistake ? when i press submit after putting the UserID. it doesnt show anything

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
SELECT u.* r.* 
FROM users as u 
LEFT JOIN ranks as r on r.UserID = u.UserID 
WHERE u.UserID = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Following code will give you the combines result of the Two tables.
The result will contain only the common data of the both tables.

```
SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN ranks ON  users.userid=ranks.userid;
```

Comment: only the common data?

Comment: And where is your  where clause on your query?

Comment: Using INNER JOIN, you can only the common data.

Comment: You can use OUTER join for the further purpose,

Comment: You can add the WHERE condition after this code as your need, but mention the field clearly like `ranks.userid="12"`